# Type 'Subject<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to add a load in my aplication, but my HTML has a problem.

I declared the variable like that:

```
public loading: Subject<boolean> = this.loaderService.isLoading
```

and that's my HTML:

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" | async></ngx-loading>
```

The error occurs in "[show]"

Comment: The pipe is _outside_ the value...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" | async></ngx-loading>
```

to

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading | async"></ngx-loading>
```